# Angular - Host Listener/UnloadNotification - History is Still Altered Even When Confirmation is Denied

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser, router, angular9

I'm working in an Angular 9 project.
I have a form, and I want to alert users if they had unsaved changes to the form and was attempting to navigate. For my router navigation, I use a basic CanDeactive Route Guard, but I need to use a HostListener to alert users when they try to navigate outside my router or using browser actions (by using back/forward button, refresh, or entering a new url into the browser's url input). I used this:

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (this.myForm?.dirty) {
      $event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }
```

It seemed to have been working as expected, except I noticed a strange little bug.
If the form is dirty, and I attempt to navigate, I am prompted (as expected). If I cancel the prompt (which cancels the navigation) I remain where I am (no navigation seems to occur, which is expected).

However, the forward button becomes enabled, and there is now history to the forward history state. In fact it even seems to remove the last history state, even when the navigation is cancelled.

Here's more depth:
If I have the been to the following routes (in order):
`/tab1`,
`/tab2`,
`/tab3`,
`/tab4`,
`/myFormPage`

and then I make changes to the form (on `/myFormPage` route) and attempt to navigate, I get the prompt. I can see in the URL that the attempted navigation will be to `/tab4`. If I cancel the prompt, I am not navigated, but my forward button becomes enabled and has history behind it. If I try to navigate again, the attempted navigation url will be to `/tab3`, when the expectation will be that it will be to `./tab4`, since it was cancelled before.

Basically, I think the history is still being altered even through the HostListener prevents navigation (if the user cancels the prompt).
How can I resolve this? Is there a way to signal to the browser that I don't want my history altered, or do I have to do it manually.

This happens in chrome, firefox, and safari.

I made a stackblitz where you can view this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-lx5wwh

Comment: Looks like an interesting problem. Can you please reproduce this on https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: I whipped one up, However something is happening here that doesn't in my actual app, here the route is actually changing (but you're not navigating). In my app the route returns to what it was if you cancel the prompt. (BTW I didn't add the route guard here, just the listener, which is what I'm having an issue with.) I hope this can help find a solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-lx5wwh?

Comment: If anyone know anything about this, I could really use the help!